# Remove border on .Background_img in CSS/HTML?

Tags: html, css

I'm fairly new to coding, and I feel like this problem has an easy solution. When I open my HTML in chrome, there is a border around the entire .Background_img. I've tried adjusting .Background_img width over 100% in CSS, the result was a blown out image in HTML. My border is also set to 0.

```
.Background_img{
width: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
left: 0px;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: can you try setting the outline to none? like this `outline: none`

Comment: that should already remove the border. But try img{border:0;}

Comment: What does your html look like?

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] in the question?  Or post a screenshot of the issue?  Also, regarding posts recommending removing `outline`: please note that [removing `outline` styles is an accessibility antipattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline#accessibility_concerns) and should generally be avoided.

Comment: Try this and see if it works? `.Background_img img { border: 0; }` .

Comment: can you share your html and css code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I assume. I think it because `HTML body` has default `margin` of `8px` that is why your background is not fully 100% on your browser.

See reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html

Try adding to this to your style:

```
body {
   margin: 0 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to give your answer, hope this works:

---

### For removing Border

Include border=0 if you used IMG tag to display image,

```
<img src="..." border=0>
```

and
CSS Code:

```
 .Background_img{
       border:0; 
       text-decoration:none; 
       outline:none;
      }
```

### For setting your image on fullscreen:

```
body, html {
       height: 100%;
       margin: 0;
    }

 .Background_img{
       height:100%;
       background-position: center;
       background-repeat: no-repeat;
       background-size: cover;
    }
```